# SAS macro reference not resolved

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I have macros in my code that are created and used in random order.

It's showing "reference not resolved" for "%put &pincuk", and syntax error for the "&pincuk". It works fine when I run the code twice. I'm guessing it happens when SAS is reaching the &pincuk before the macro is created. For example,

```
data x.fcastukcalc;
do day=&daycountuk + 1 to &daycountkorea
retain fcast &ukdmax;
fcast=(fcast * &pincuk) + fcast;
output;
end;
run;



/* then this, later on */

data _null_;
keep deathsuk inc1 inc2 pinc1 pinc2 pinc;
set x.uk;
inc1=deathsuk - lag1(deathsuk);
pinc1=(inc1 / lag1(deathsuk));
inc2=lag1 (deathsuk) - lag2(deathsuk);
pinc2=(inc2 / lag2(deathsuk));
pinc=(pinc1 + pinc2) / 2;
call symputx('pincuk', pinc);
run;

%put &pincUK;
```

Comment: The only place you show the macro variable PINCUK being created is at the end of data _null_ step, but you referenced it earlier in the first data step. Which statement is causing the error message?

Comment: Everything seems to create a log error at first, then on the second run they all disappear. "Apparent symbolic reference not resolved" and "Syntax error, expecting one of the following..." Is there a way of creating a macro variable and then adding it to a previous data step? If not that's probably where I've gone wrong.

Comment: *Is there a way of creating a macro variable and then adding it to a previous data step?* Only with a time machine.  You can set an initial value using a `%LET` statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If, on the first run through, `x.uk` does not exist, or has zero rows, the `call symputx('pincUK',pinc);` will never be reached.  So, in a 'random' situation of code running, lets be more generous and say a **developmental** situation, your expectations may have been subverted by a misremembered operation or subtle change of state.  Check your code for `%SYMDEL` statements.  During development of a large macro, you may be submitting parts of the interior of a macro and not have complete 'simulation' of the state expected to exist during an actual call of the macro.

Start a fresh SAS session and see if the problem with the code persists and can be reproduced more directly.

To be specific, your question is about macro **symbols**, often referred to as macro variables. *Macros* themselves are names for groups of SAS programming statements.

From [help (good read)](https://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=mcrolref&docsetTarget=p1ccprwibo8gvqn1q6zinvjlzuut.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en)

> When SAS compiles program text, two delimiters trigger macro processor activity:
>
> *&name*
>
> - refers to a macro variable. [Replacing Text Strings Using Macro Variables](https://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=mcrolref&docsetTarget=n1nks63d6g1rk2n1owajhi374c6w.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en) explains how to create a macro variable. The form *&name* is called a macro variable reference.
>
> %name
>
> - refers to a macro. [Generating SAS Code Using Macros](https://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=mcrolref&docsetTarget=n0pfmkjlc3e719n1lks4go8ke61r.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en) explains how to create a macro. The form *%name* is called a macro call.
>
> The text substitution produced by the macro processor is completed before the program text is compiled and executed. The macro facility uses statements and functions that resemble the statements and functions that you use in the DATA step. An important difference, however, is that macro language elements can enable only text substitution and are not present during program or command execution.

------ Edit (added) ------

Writing code with lots of abstractions (i.e. macro variables) requires a certain level of discipline and system design.  A *macro* must be compiled before it can be called, however the macro variables (i.e. symbols) it resolves within do NOT need to exist at compilation time, only at macro invocation (call) time.  For old fuddies the concept is like a mail merge boilerplate with too many fields.

Macro variables can be local (as a parameter in the macro definition, or explicitly stated in a `%LOCAL`, or as an assignment to a previously undefined symbol.  Reliance on *GLOBAL* macro variables should be reduced to a minimum or none, as should an over-reliance on variables to be expected to exist in the caller scope. Dependence on a variable being global should be explicitly stated with a `%GLOBAL` in the macros source.

An assignment to a non-declared `%LOCAL` can be a problem because the assignment *could* accidentally (unexpectedly) replace the value of a declared or existing variable in an outer (or calling) scope, and be the cause of *it don't work right* problems.  Good discipline is to explicitly `%LOCAL` all variables within a macro definition - the macro system does **not** have a *strict mode* (as found in other languages) that reports problematic macro variables.

Comment: Hi Richard, thanks for your reply. I didn't use any %SYMDEL statements and it works the same after a refresh. I'm guessing I've created a macro variable and then tried to use it before it was created in the code which is not possible. The only fix I could imagine would be to ask SAS to scan for macro variables and create them first, or group and run them all at the beginning.

Comment: When I say random order, I just mean I used the macro variables throughout the code, even if they are created further on in the code. I created and used lots of them too which makes it difficult to just switch the order.